# Setting up a virtual host on XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I am trying to set up a virtualhost on my apple mac on localhost. The server is provided by XAMPP . but just Apache Web Server and proFTPD statuses are running and mySQL Database is stopped . i tried to change configuration mySQL Database and change port but does not give me running status . 
this is my conf File :

```
> # Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
 # other programs (such as a web server)
#
   # You can copy this file to
   # /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
  # mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
 # installation this directory is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql) or
   # ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
 #
   # In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
 # If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
  # with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
 [client]
  #password = your_password
 port       = 3306
 socket     = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

 # Here follows entries for some specific programs

  # The MySQL server
 [mysqld]
 user = mysql
 port=3306
 socket     = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
 skip-external-locking
 key_buffer = 16M
 max_allowed_packet = 1M
 table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/plugin/

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,    
#  if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
#  Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
 #skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
#  defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
 server-id  = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
 # The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
 # the master - required
 #master-password =   <password>
 #
 # The port the master is listening on.
 # optional - defaults to 3306
 #master-port     =  <port>
 #
 # binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
 #log-bin=mysql-bin


  # Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
 tmpdir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/mysql
 #log-update    = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
 #bdb_cache_size = 4M
  #bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
# Deprecated in 5.6
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

 [mysqldump]
 quick
 max_allowed_packet = 16M

 [mysql]
 no-auto-rehash
 # Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
 #safe-updates

 [isamchk]
 key_buffer = 20M
 sort_buffer_size = 20M
 read_buffer = 2M
 write_buffer = 2M

 [myisamchk]
 key_buffer = 20M
 sort_buffer_size = 20M
 read_buffer = 2M
 write_buffer = 2M

 [mysqlhotcopy]
 interactive-timeout
```

how can i change MySQL Database status to running. Is there any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
    sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start